# Learning in Markov Random fields

Tags: markov-random-field

I have a question about learning in Markov random fields.

According to the explanation https://ermongroup.github.io/cs228-notes/learning/undirected/
we have

$P(x_{1},\ldots, x_{n}) = \frac{1}{Z(\psi)} \exp[\sum_{c \in C}\sum_{x'}1_{x'_{c} = x_{c}} \log(\phi_{c}(x'_{c}, \psi))]$.

Now they go on and say

$P(x_{1},\ldots, x_{n}) = \frac{1}{Z(\theta)} \exp[\theta^{\intercal} f(x)]$.

I understood that $\theta$ is the vector containing all values $\log(\phi_{c}(x'_{c}, \phi))$, and $f(x)$ is a binary vector such that $\theta^{\intercal} f(x) = \sum_{c \in C}\sum_{x'}1_{x'_{c} = x_{c}} \log(\phi_{c}(x'_{c}, \phi))$.

Then why is the denominator changing ?

Comment: This just about notation. They're performing a reparameterization, so they want to talk in terms of $\theta$ instead of $\phi$. $Z$ can be determined either from $\phi$ or $\theta$.

Comment: Ok, to make it more precise: In my opinion $Z(\psi) = Z(\theta)$ holds. Is that correct ?

Comment: Yes, that’s correct.